# How a real packet should be constructed?

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

Probably this question will anger all stack overflow gods, but I just cant get my head around how a packet should look like.

I mean how to make a packet by these guidelines?

[image: sample packet]
.

```
byte[] data0 = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("1");
byte[] data1 = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(0x03);
string data2 = "127.0.0.0:80";
string data3 = "";
```

I imagine everything like this and make a **byte list/array** out of this?
Or that string has to be converted to byte and then pack it to **array/list**?

Or maybe someone has a simple explanation how its done?

Comment: Are you socking about the underlying IP structure?  Why?  Doesn't the .NET APIs encapsulate this for you?

Comment: There is not enough information in your picture to give you a real answer. The only thing we can tell you is that the first byte is `0x31`. Strings also need to have a length identifier (unless the fields are fixed-length), which is probably explained below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be trying to implement a client to use Valve's ["Master Server Query Protocol"](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Master_Server_Query_Protocol). If you click on the ["String Zero"](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/String_Zero) link, you'll find it simply describes a null-terminated string. Presumably the encoding is ASCII, but I don't see anything in the documentation that makes that clear.

You will need to construct a datagram with the bytes formatted as described in the document. For ASCII characters, you can just cast `char` to `int`; for non-ASCII characters, you'd get values outside the valid range for ASCII, but `char` uses UTF16 which, for the range of characters shared with ASCII also shares the actual *value* for the character. You can then cast that character to `byte` for the purpose of the datagram. However, none of this really matters in this particular example because the only part of the protocol described as a specific character, you already know the byte value for and so can just specify that explicitly.

To build up the `byte[]` for the datagram, I'd recommend using `MemoryStream` (you could also use `BinaryWriter` for more complex types of data, but here you're really only dealing with bytes…`BinaryWriter` uses its own length-prefixed format for strings, so you'd have to convert to `byte[]` for the strings anyway). Something like the following ought to work:

```
byte[] GetMasterServerQueryDatagram(byte regionCode, string address, string filter)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

    stream.WriteByte(0x31);
    stream.WriteByte(regionCode);
    byte[] stringZero = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(address + "\0");
    stream.Write(stringZero, 0, stringZero.Length);
    stringZero = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(filter + "\0");
    stream.Write(stringZero, 0, stringZero.Length);

    return stream.ToArray();
}
```

Notes:

- You might want to declare an `enum` based on the table in the Valve documentation to represent the `regionCode` value, so that your other code can refer to the region by name.
- Pay close attention to the requirement in the documentation that you pass `"0.0.0.0:0"` as the first `IP:port` value, but then pass the *last* value returned by their servers in your subsequent queries.